# Download revision history from cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

How do I download the revision history of a file from cloud9? I can view it in cloud9, but for documentation purposes, I need to be able to review it offline. An alternate solution would be instructions on how to copy a file from one workspace to another while keeping the file revision history.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to copy a file from one workspace to another while also keeping the history as the history is stored in the database, not in the file itself. There is no way to download the revision history for a file.